# Insert Image tag after opening div tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on the following jQuery code. Assuming I have the following HTML code sample:

```
<div class="my-class"> 
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

With jQuery, I need add the following `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">` immediately after the opening `div my-class` tag. I need to target the `my-class` class selector.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
<div class="my-class">
   <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$('div.my-class').after('<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">');
```

but this inserts it after the closing div tag, which is not what I am after.

Comment: `.prepend()` is the answer

Comment: I think this is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527911/how-to-insert-element-as-a-first-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `.prepend()` like:

```
$('div.my-class').prepend('<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">');
```

`.after()` will add the html after the closing tag of the subject element.

`.append()` will place it inside the div but after `<h1>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this :)

```js
$('div.my-class').prepend('<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-class"> 
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```